# Spell checker settings intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent

In Android, I can launch the *Keyboard & Input* Settings dialog using the `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` intent:

```
getPresenter().startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
```

**Question:**
How can I open the "Spell Checker" settings dialog (available in Jelly Bean+) so that the user can enable my service?

**Example:**
I can get to it from the *Language & Input* settings:
[image: Language and input settings]

But I want to take the user directly to this screen:
[image: Spell Checker settings]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ComponentName componentToLaunch = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
        "com.android.settings.Settings$SpellCheckersSettingsActivity");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(componentToLaunch);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //TODO
        }
```

You can find out the names of other Activities by starting the Activity and lookup the Intent used in Logcat. The output for me was:

```
I/ActivityManager(  589): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$SpellCheckersSettingsActivity} from pid 13084
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you for the activity tip - that'll come in useful.

Comment: Careful, there are devices that don't have this feature in settings (at least my Samsung 4.2.2 doesn't have it). So you should check first if above activity resolves to something

Comment: @gunar AFAIK, the dialog only shows when you have at least one 3rd party spell checker installed. Since my application contains one, I should be guaranteed that all JB devices can see this dialog.

Comment: I didn't know you can install a spell checker :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is Possible..:)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$SpellCheckersSettingsActivity"));
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

We create an explicit intent, and we have to launch the com.android.settings.Settings$SpellCheckersSettingsActivity component. For Future Reference, You can use LogCat in eclipse to find whatever package or component you are trying to launch. Just look at the ActivityManager's Starting activity messages and you will see the package and component name of any Activity.

Comment: How is this answer posted after 13 mins different from previous?

Comment: I see what you meant. But damn Facebook Got my attention..:p. Lost my Bounty..:\